# In nodereference field of a content type, Is it possible to show the content type name added with the autocomplete results?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

In nodereference field of a content type, Is it possible to show the content type name added with the autocomplete results ?

### Example :

I have a content type named Article which has a node reference field (Related content -> field_related_documents), So that this article will referenced to other nodes.

While creating an article, by entering 'help' in 'field_related_documents' I am getting autocomplete results (titles of referenced nodes) like below

```
helpsystems - rules 
Decision management Help
Using help menu
Help support glossary
```

Instead, I like to show results like below

```
Page | helpsystems - rules
HelpSystems | Decision management Help
Page | Using help menu
Document | Help support glossary
```

ie) autocomplete results should display title of other nodes added with their related content type.

How should i achieve this ? Is there any contributed modules available to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new custom Module nodereference_patch with below hook

```
/*
 * Altering nodereference/autocomplete menu using menu alter
 */
function nodereference_patch_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['nodereference/autocomplete']['page callback'] = 'nodereference_patch_new_nodereference_autocomplete';
}
```

Then, I copied the nodereference_autocomplete function into your custom module, changing it's name to nodereference_patch_new_nodereference_autocomplete.

Then I changed this line:

```
$matches[$row['title'] ." [nid:$id]"] = '<div class="reference-autocomplete">'. $row['rendered'] . '</div>';
```

to

```
$matches[$row['type'] . " | " . $row['title'] . " [nid:$id]"] = '<div class="reference-autocomplete">' . $row['type'] . " | " . $row['rendered'] . '</div>';
```

I copied _nodereference_potential_references function from nodereference.module to custom module and renamed it as _nodereference_patch_potential_references

Then I changed the following line as

```
$references = _nodereference_potential_references_standard($field, $string, $match, $ids, $limit);
```

to

```
$references = _nodereference_patch_potential_references_standard($field, $string, $match, $ids, $limit);
```

I copied _nodereference_potential_references_standard from nodereference.module to custom module and renamed it as _nodereference_patch_potential_references_standard

Then I added 'type' element to $references[]. ie) changed following array from

```
$references[$node->nid] = array(
    'title' => $node->node_title,
    'rendered' => check_plain($node->node_title),
);
```

to

```
$references[$node->nid] = array(
    'title' => $node->node_title,
    'type' => $node->node_type,
    'rendered' => check_plain($node->node_title),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be more inclined to use a different approach, using similar methods but rather than copying the full module and renaming this I'd create a new menu_hook and form_alters to update the autocomplete path.

If you're using entity reference rather than node reference you can use views to display the content, not my preferred route but will reduce the amount of custom code. Quick google of a demonstration of this gives the following video (http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/using-views-entity-reference-module-drupal-7)

Also, just a note, if you plan to copy the module out like the above answer I would strongly advise to remove some of the lines from the module info file. The information below '; Information added by drupal.org packaging script on' in the info file is used by the update module and increases the risk of this new module being replaced by the original module.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Anthony Leach. My Info file looks like ////****  core = "6.x"
name = "NodeReference Patch"
project = "nodereference_patch"
dependencies[] = nodereference
description = "Modifies autocomplete result of nodereference field"
package = "CCK"
version = "6.x-1.0"    ****//// What change i should apply here?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/231036 Both the 'project' and 'version' are discouraged because these are added from the drupal.org packaging script. I'm not sure this will be a problem leaving these in, but I'd more than likely remove these for peace of mind.